# Getting module name in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I am playing around with MVVM (leveraging Prism and Unity), but I am somewhat stuck on how I would go about getting the name of a given module. At design time I don't know which modules a given user will have access to, so the display needs to be dynamic. So if I had 3 modules, but the user could only access Module 1 and Module 3, the structure of my container would be similar to the following:

##########    Container  ################

================Module 1 Text=======

------------- View     1 Text------------------

------------- View     2 Text------------------

------------- View     3 Text------------------

================Module 3 Text=======

------------- View     1 Text------------------

------------- View     2 Text------------------

I know (basically) how to get 'View X Text' to display through the use of a ViewModel, but I am not sure how I would set the text of a given module properly.

For reference, my Bootstrapper.cs file looks something like this:

```
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        // Use the container to create an instance of the shell.
        var view = Container.TryResolve<AppShell>();
        return view;
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();

        Application.Current.MainWindow = (Window)Shell;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }
    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        var catalog = new ModuleCatalog();
        catalog.AddModule(typeof(Module1));
        //catalog.AddModule(typeof(Module2));
        catalog.AddModule(typeof(Module3));
        return catalog;
    }
```

Any help that you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: What would exactly be the Text referenced on the Modules? The structure you described is showing how they would display in the App or just the Container hierarchy registration? I don't completely understand why or how you would like to add a Text on the Container Registration. However, if you want to display the Module section with some Text, you could create a ModuleView with the Text configured, and an ItemsControl Region where you would register the related Views. Regards.

Comment: The text would be the name of the module.  Think about Outlook for a moment; it has 4 default "modules": Mail, Calendar, Contacts, and Tasks.  So if Module1 in my code above where the Mail Module, then I would expect 'Mail' to be displayed in my UI and so on.

Answer (score 0):

A possible simple solution would be the one I commented above, which I will expand below:

Each **Module** would define and configure their corresponding **Views**, so the **Views** would know to which **Module** they belong at *CompileTime*. Therefore, in order to generate and display the structure described in the question, a ***`"ModuleXView"`*** View page could be created on each **Module**, being ***"X"*** the corresponding **Module** number.

This **View** would contain for example a `TextArea` at the top showing the *ModuleName*, and a ***`"ModuleXRegion"`*** definition (*ItemsControl*) in order to *Register* and show the corresponding ***Module's Views*** listed in it. Each `ModuleXView` would know to which **Module** it belongs. So, there is no need to bind the *ModuleName*, and the `TextArea` would configure each *ModuleName* statically.

If I wasn't clear enough, based on the **Outlook** example, `Module1` would have a ***`"Module1View"`***, which its `TextArea` value would be set to "Mail"; ***`Module2View`*** would set its `TextArea` value to "Calendar", and so on.

Finally, if you would like to have each **Module** in a different tab for example, you would simply need to register each ***`ModuleXView`*** on the `TabControl` *Region* (defined in a parent view), so every `Tab` would show the ***`ModuleXView`*** page structure.

I hope this helped you, Regards.